# Dependency Version Conflict

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit

I have an '.aar' that uses a version of retrofit 1.9 and in the project I'm using this file it uses a version of retrofit 2.1.0.
This is conflicting when instantiating the RequestInterceptor. Displays the NoClassDefFoundError run-time error.
Would you have some way of keeping the two working properly even though the version is deferential?
Any way to force 'aar' to use only 1.9 and project 2.1.0?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means class is not present in that version. there is not any way to make it work. unless you copy the required classes from that library to your code. not a good practice though. i suggest use compatible versions

Comment: That's a shame ... I thought there was some way to isolate the versions, being 'aar' 1.9 and projects in 2.1 using some gradle command.